# How to get order id and other details of order for given event observer

Tags: magento-1.9, module, extensions, event-observer

How to get order id and other details of order for **sales_order_payment_cancel** event observer. i know how to get them for **checkout_onepage_controller_success_action**. But that method is not working in it. And showing this error.

Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in /home/orderitonline/public_html/includes/src/Barcatsia_Smsntf_Model_Observer.php on line 108

```
<sales_order_payment_cancel>
                <observers>
                    <Barcatsia_Smsntf_Model_Observer_cancelOrder>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Barcatsia_Smsntf_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>smsntf_cancel_order</method>
                    </Barcatsia_Smsntf_Model_Observer_cancelOrder>
                </observers>
           </sales_order_payment_cancel>
```

-

```
public function smsntf_cancel_order($observer){


        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $orderIds = $order->getId();




        if(Mage::getStoreConfig

('testsection/cancel_order/Smsntf_module_activation')){

        $layout = Mage::app()->getLayout();


            $order     = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderIds);            

        $message_for_send = Mage::getStoreConfig

('testsection/cancel_order/Smsntf_text_field_msg');
        $http_url = Mage::getStoreConfig

('testsection/cancel_order/Smsntf_text_field_api_calling_url');
        $arr_params = array('Smsntf_text_field_authkey', 'Smsntf_text_field_mobile', 

'Smsntf_text_field_senderid', 'Smsntf_text_field_routeid', 'Smsntf_text_field_additional', 

'Smsntf_text_field_additional', 'Smsntf_text_field_additional1', 

'Smsntf_text_field_additional2', 'Smsntf_text_field_additional3', 

'Smsntf_text_field_additional4');

        //replaceing %O% with Order Number
        $message_for_send = str_replace('%O%',100000000+intval($orderIds[0]),

$message_for_send);

        //replaceing %N% with Mobile Number
        $message_for_send = str_replace('%N%',$order->getdata

('customer_firstname'),$message_for_send);

        //replaceing %A% with Grand Total
        $message_for_send = str_replace('%A%',$order->getdata('grand_total'),

$message_for_send);

        $http_url .='?'. Mage::getStoreConfig

('testsection/cancel_order/Smsntf_text_field_Msg_prm').'='.urlencode($message_for_send);
        for($a=0; $a<sizeof($arr_params); $a++){
            if(trim(Mage::getStoreConfig('testsection/cancel_order/'.

$arr_params[$a]))!=''){
                if(trim($arr_params[$a])!='Smsntf_text_field_mobile')
                    $http_url .= '&'.Mage::getStoreConfig

('testsection/cancel_order/'.$arr_params[$a]);
                else
                    $http_url .= '&'.Mage::getStoreConfig

('testsection/cancel_order/'.$arr_params[$a]).'='.$order->getBillingAddress()->getData

('telephone');
            }       
        }

        //printing system->configuration inputs value
        //      echo Mage::getStoreConfig

('testsection/cancel_order/active');
                $this->send_sms($http_url);

        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can please show code of `Barcatsia_Smsntf_Model_Observer`

Comment: try `$Observer->getPayment()->getOrder()->getId()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to *get order object* from **`sales_order_payment_cancel`** at observer then you can try:

*`$OrderObject=$observer->getEvent()->getPayment()->getOrder()`*

And from order object ***$OrderObject***,you can *get all order related details*

**Edit:**

just change `$observer->getEvent()->getOrder()` to  `$observer->getEvent()->getPayment()->getOrder()`

Comment: when i am printing whole object data is too much long and page get hanged. that is why i am asking how to get order id

Comment: for getting id try `$order->getId()` and Increment id  `$order->getIncrementId()`

Comment: why its give same error in third line?                                                             $payment = $observer->getEvent()->getPayment();
  $order = $payment->getOrder();
  $orderIds = $order->getId();

Comment: i changed this code **$observer->getEvent()->getOrder() to  $Observer->getEvent()->getPayment()->getOrder()**                                                                          Now its showing  this error                   **Fatal error: Call to a member function getEvent() on a non-object in**

Comment: just variable issue  `$Observer` should be `$observer`

Answer (score 2):

Observers will give you different variables, so be careful when you use them. In your case, this observer only passes the payment information `Mage::dispatchEvent('sales_order_payment_cancel', array('payment' => $this));`. So what you are after is:

```
$payment = $observer->getEvent()->getPayment();
$order = $payment->getOrder();
```

Comment: i know its return order object. but how to get order id from order object

Comment: Just do `$orderId = $order->getId();`

Comment: why its give same error in third line?                                                             $payment = $observer->getEvent()->getPayment();
  $order = $payment->getOrder();
  $orderIds = $order->getId();